# Definition of Rejected and Failed in Support Cipher Suite

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, ssl

When I using SSLSCAN to check the cipher suites of my server, I found that there are three status: Accepted, Rejected and Failed. After that, I tried to disable the ciphers of RC2(40bits). I created a new key "Enabled"=dword:00000000 under 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\RC2 40/128]. The SSLSCAN showed EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5 (40bits) was "failed" but the rest of RC2 （40bits） ciphers were "Rejected".

So this made me confused: what the difference between failed and rejected? I came across all the information on the google, including SSLSCAN main page, but haven't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 3):

I wondered about the same thing, looked at the source code (*“Use the source, Luke!”* :), and it simply is the *return value* of [`SSL_connect()` from the OpenSSL library](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_connect.html). The documentation states that:

- `Accepted` (`1`) means:

  > The TLS/SSL handshake was **successfully** completed, a TLS/SSL connection has been **established**.
- `Rejected` (`0`) means:

  > The TLS/SSL handshake was ***not* successful** but was **shut down controlled** and by the specifications of the TLS/SSL protocol. Call `SSL_get_error()` with the return value ret to find out the reason.
- `Failed` (`<0`) means:

  > The TLS/SSL handshake was ***not* successful**, because a **fatal error** occurred either at the protocol level **or** a **connection failure** occurred. The shutdown was **not clean**. *It can also occur [if] action is need to continue the operation for non-blocking BIOs.* Call `SSL_get_error()` with the return value ret to find out the reason.

The latter two can be followed by a `N/A`, if *https* is not available.

So I think `sslscan` should contain a `--verbose` or `-v` option that calls [`SSL_get_error()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_error.html) and outputs the actual reason it failed (or was rejected).
That would be rather useful. Because right now, it isn’t.

**For now, all I can recommend is to manually connect with a more real-world client, force the usage of a certain cipher on said client or on the server, and then have it show you the actual reason.**
Unless you want to improve `sslscan`’s code, of course. :)